# Javascript switch which shows new set of buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble trying to make a switch in Javascript that when the switch activates, depending on the case, the program will display a number of new buttons which you can click and will play a sound.

This is my HTML and Javascript with the first set of buttons:

```js
function selectchord(){
  var userinput = document.getElementById("chord").value;
  switch (userinput) {
      case "a":
        document.write("holas");
        break;
  }
}

function PlaySound(path) {
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElement.setAttribute('src', path);
  audioElement.play();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="chord"></input>
<button onclick="selectchord()">Select chord</button>

<p id="demo"></p>   

<button id="bt" type="button"
  onclick="javascript:PlaySound('sounds/Am.wav');">
  A minor
</button>

<button id="bt" type="button"
  onclick="javascript:PlaySound('sounds/Bm.wav');">
  B minor
</button>
```

In the case above, I just put in the switch there to see if it worked. I am really new to Javascript so I apologise if I am not using the correct terminology.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your code...

I do not know exactly your intentions, but I think you are trying to do something like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('selectChord');
button.addEventListener('click', selectChord, false);

function selectChord() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById("chord").value.toLowerCase(),
      html = '';
  
  switch (userinput) {
    case "a":
      html += '<button id="A" onclick="playSound(this.id)">A</button>';
      html += '<button id="Am" onclick="playSound(this.id)">Am</button>';    
      break;
    case "b":
      html += '<button id="B" onclick="playSound(this.id)">B</button>';
      html += '<button id="Bm" onclick="playSound(this.id)">Bm</button>';
      break;
    default:
      html += '<p>Oops!</p>';
  }

  document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = html;
}

function playSound(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```css
#buttons {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="chord">
<button id="selectChord">Select chord</button>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```